# Creating a categorical variable from two dummy variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data;

```
{'ID': {0: 5531.0, 1: 2658.0, 2: 5365.0, 3: 4468.0, 4: 3142.0},
 'FEMALE': {0: 1.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 1.0},
 'MALE': {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 0.0},
 'AGE': {0: 45.0, 1: 40.0, 2: 38.0, 3: 43.0, 4: 38.0},
 'S': {0: 12.0, 1: 12.0, 2: 15.0, 3: 13.0, 4: 18.0}}
```

Where MALE is a dummy equal to one if the individual is male, 0 otherwise. The same for FEMALE.
I want to create a new variable, Gender, which is categorical. If MALE==1 then Gender = Male, if FEMALE==1 then Gender = Female. The purpose is to allow for a clear twoway scatter plot seperated by gender. I can do this currently, but the legend is hard to understand.

I tried the following;

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
stata_data_P1  = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 5531.0, 1: 2658.0, 2: 5365.0, 3: 4468.0, 4: 3142.0}, 'FEMALE': {0: 1.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 1.0}, 'MALE': {0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 0.0}, 'AGE': {0: 45.0, 1: 40.0, 2: 38.0, 3: 43.0, 4: 38.0}, 'S': {0: 12.0, 1: 12.0, 2: 15.0, 3: 13.0, 4: 18.0}})

stata_data_P1['Gender'] = np.where(stata_data_P1['MALE'] == '1', 'Female', 'Male')

stata_data_P1.head()
```

But from stata_data_P1.head() we can see it doesn't seem to have taken on board my command for true and false values.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `stata_data_P1['MALE'] == '1'` the `1` here should be an int or float not a string: `stata_data_P1['MALE'] == 1` because `stata_data_P1['MALE'] == '1'` will return False for all the values in your frame.

Comment: VTC as typo. `1 != '1'`. https://www.online-python.com/zfVCXntaxk

Answer (score 0):

First use *assign* method to create new column then use *idxmax* just in MALE and FEMALE columns to return the index for the maximum value in each row.

**Code:**

```
stata_data_P1.assign(GENDER=lambda df_: df_.loc[:, ["MALE", "FEMALE"]].idxmax(axis=1))
```

**Documentation:**

- [Pandas - idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)
- [Pandas - assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)